# "Run"ing vs. Single stepping in Java Eclipse -

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, macos, debugging

I am trying to update a large (~150,000 line) Java/Eclipse program from 2009 that has several threads, and communicates with a TCP-IP telescope.  I wrote new code to do the communications, and that all works fine when separately tested.  This is on a Mac - the original worked on Mac OSX 10.6 and nothing later - I'm writing this for current Mac OS 12.xx

In the overall program, there is a thread that receives mouse clicks from the GUI and initiates operation of a thread with runs the communications code.  The communications thread stays alive, using parameters passed to it to determine which communication function to execute.

Here's some of the code:

```
class ActualTask {
    ActualTask ()  {
        // PRAA Dec 7 2021
        System.out.println("What thread are we in? it's: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
        while (true) // this is true so we can keep reusing this task!
        {
            // PRAA Dec 7 2021
            //System.out.println("What thread are we in? it's: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());

            if (running)
            {
                // PRAA Dec 7 2021
                System.out.println("Just before call to run() - What thread are we in? it's: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                
                run();
                // PRAA Dec 7 2021
                System.out.println("What thread are we in? it's: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ------------------------------------

    void run()
    {                   
        done = false;
        successful = true;
        telescopeException = null;
        // PRAA Dec 7 2021
        System.out.println("In run() -  thread is: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
        
        try
        {   // *** execute the telescope task ***
        
            TelescopeGlobals.telescopeProgressTaskData.setBackgroundColor(Color.red); // red when active
            
            telescopeTask.execute();
                            
            done = true;
            
            TelescopeGlobals.telescopeProgressTaskData.setBackgroundColor(Color.white); // white when NOT active
        }
        catch (TelescopeException te)
        {
            // Clear progress bar before throwing up dialog
            
            TelescopeGlobals.telescopeProgressTaskData.setBackgroundColor(Color.white); // white when NOT active

            TelescopeGlobals.telescopeProgressTaskData.clear();
                            
            done = true;
            successful = false;
            telescopeException = te;
            
            Reporting.selctiveAlert(te.getMessage() + "\n" + te.getWhereExceptionOccured()); 
            
            
            TelescopeGlobals.telescopeProgressTaskData.setText1("Error: " + te.getMessage());   
            TelescopeGlobals.telescopeProgressTaskData.setText2("Where: " + te.getWhereExceptionOccured());     

        }

        done = true;
    }
}
```

When I am in "debug" mode, and I single-step through the communications code, things usually execute properly - however, when I hit "Run", things don't go so well -

- the first call works ok
- the second call appears to do nothing - that is, it doesn't seem to be executing, and none of my print statements print
- subsequent calls only print an error message saying the previous task has not completed.

So I'm wondering - what is the difference between the "run" and "debug" modes - why would one work and the other behave differently - and

Does all of the "SwingWorker" stuff from 2009 still work?

Should creating the communications thread be done differently?  It is just created once, as shown in the code snippet below:

```
// Static member above of HighLevelTaskWorker makes sure that one command is dispatched to the telescope at a time.
```

class HighLevelTaskWorker { // SwingWorker wrapper class

```
private lib.SwingWorker worker = null;

private boolean done;
private boolean successful;
private TelescopeException telescopeException;

private boolean running;

private TelescopeTask telescopeTask;

public HighLevelTaskWorker()
{
}

public void start(TelescopeTask telescopeTask) {
        
    this.telescopeTask = telescopeTask;
    
    // PRAA Dec 7 2021
    System.out.println("What thread are we in? it's: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    
    
    
    
    done = false;
    successful = false;
    telescopeException = null;
    running = true;

    if (worker == null) // no need to create this tread over and over again, think of all that Garbage Collecting and tread creation!
    {
        worker = new lib.SwingWorker() {
            public Object construct() {
                return new ActualTask();
            }
    

        };
        worker.start();
    }

}
```

Thanks so much for any help !!!

Comment: Why is there an infinite loop in the `ActualTask` constructor? Why does the constructor call the `run()` method directly (in the same thread)? What is `lib.SwingWorker`? That doesn't appear to be a `javax.swing.SwingWorker`. What calls `construct()`? It certainly will not ever return, since the `ActualTask` constructor can never complete. What is the `done` variable used for? You don't show any loops that go until done is true.

Comment: David - Thanks so much for reading and commenting.

Comment: David - Thanks so much for reading and commenting.  Answers: ActualTask stays alive for the duration of the application, only calling run() when there is a task given to it by the GUI. (I'm wondering whether to change this). My guess is lib.SwingWorker is Apple's implementation of javax.swing.SwingWorker. The GUI call the constructor (my second example) in the start code.  As far as I can see, the "done" variable is never used.  Thanks so much for your thoughts !  Paul

Comment: Staying alive for the duration of the application sounds like something that would be done by starting a thread, not by putting an infinite loop inside the constructor so that it can never finish. Typically a class with a run() method implements Runnable, and the run() method is called by the Thread when it starts. Of course, there's no reason a method can't be called `run()` even if it doesn't implement the 'meat' of a thread, but this code is, to say the least, pretty strange. I would say that a constructor that never completes is not something you would ever, ever want to do.

Comment: David - Thanks so much for your comments.  I am quite new to Java, and have no real idea what it is supposed to look like.  (I have written zillions of lines of C code, mostly for real-time microcontrollers in instruments.   It's quite different).  I've analyzed the code for what code is in which thread, and determined that there is a communications problem between threads "AWT-EventQueue-0" and "Thread-1".  I added debug code and a short delay (Thread.sleep(2) and now the threads are communicating. I don't know how much re-writing I'm willing to do for this port, but welcome any suggestions